# SAP Web IDE & Git On-Premise

Tags: git, sap-web-ide

According to this link, it is possible to conntect to the corporate Git from SAP Web IDE:

https://help.hana.ondemand.com/webide/frameset.htm?b8427ec16ae64347b97d2d46fb28f7cd.html

I set up Git, enabled access over HTTPS, installed SAP Cloud Connector, configured Cloud to On-Premise tunnel, configured available resources, connected to the SAP Cloud Platform, created and configured the destination for the on-premise Git, enabled "Corp. Git Link for SAP Web IDE" service, checked connectivity on every step and everything seems to be fine.

Git repository in the intranet can be accessed on https://githost:4431/Repository.git (with basic authentication).

Virtual host in SAP Cloud Connector is "git", port is "4432".

Destination name in SAP Cloud Plaftorm is "GIT_HTTPS" (I tried with and without authentication).

However, I am not able to clone the repository in SAP Web IDE. No matter what I enter in the URL text box, I get "502 Host not found" error.

What URL should I specify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I have figured it out. There is a mistake in the documentation. Instead of:

> When you define the cloud connector, there are two types of hosts: Internal and Virtual. Make sure to use the **internal** host.

..one should read:

> When you define the cloud connector, there are two types of hosts: Internal and Virtual. Make sure to use the **virtual** host.

So the correct address would be:

https://git:4332/Repository.git

Comment: Seems the documentation is still not up to snuff. I have a paid (so non-trail) Web IDE Subaccount and am not able to even get through to the cloud connector. What was your setup regarding additional properties like "WebIDEEnabled"?

Comment: There days the documentation is pretty good. Have a look here: [Connect to ABAP Systems](https://help.sap.com/viewer/825270ffffe74d9f988a0f0066ad59f0/CF/en-US/5c3debce758a470e8342161457fd6f70.html)